# next.js13 fetching data with an async function and also use state?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity, next.js13

i hope you are having a great day ! i got a question... i'm currently learning next.js 13 and so i thought doing a personal project with it would be a good idea . Currently i'm doing an e-commmerce with Sanity.io as a cms .The problem i got is that im fetching data with an async function , but i want to also use "use State" hook from react to do a nice product images viewer ! the problem i got is that i can't use a hook inside of an async function ! so please if anyone got a solution to this i would  be very pleased since im really new to next.js 13 here is my code and what i want to do

```
"use client"
import { Product } from '@/component';
import { getProduct, getProducts } from '@/sanity/sanity-utils';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMinus,AiOutlinePlus,AiFillStar,AiOutlineStar} from 'react-icons/ai';

export default async function ProductDetails({ params }) {
  const slug = params.product;
  const product = await getProduct(slug);
  console.log("product",product)


  return (
    <div>
      <div className='product-detail-container'>
        <div>
        <div className='image-container'>
            <img src={product.image[0]} alt="product-image"
            className='product-detail-image'
            />
          </div>
            <div className='small-images-container'>
              {product.image.map((item, i) => (
               <img
                  src={item}
                  alt={`product-image-${i}`}
                  key={i}
                  />
                 ))}
            </div>
        </div>
```

what i really want to do is an use State to acces the images array so it shows each image when i click on it

```
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(); 
 <div className='small-images-container'>
              {product.image.map((item, i) => (
               <img
                  src={item}
                  alt={`product-image-${i}`}
                  key={i}
                  onMouseEnter={()=> setIndex(i)}
                  />
                 ))}
            </div>
```

thank you so much i hope my questions is understandable

i actually dont know what to do honestly , should i bring the data from sanity differently ?

Comment: remove "use client"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next 13 app router, you need to choose whether a component is a server component (only runs on server) or a client component (runs in browser). Components using hooks such as `useState` must be client components. On the other hand, only server components can be `async`. At the moment you're trying to use both at the same time, so its invalid.

So one option is to turn your existing `ProductDetails` component into a bona fide client component by removing the `async` keyword and moving the fetching into `useEffect` to avoid fetching on every render (or better yet, use a fetching library such as react-fetch or swr).

Alternatively, you could make `ProductDetailsFetcher` an async server component which fetches the data, then passes the `product` as a prop to a client component which does the rendering. Only the client component would have `useState`.

The best option may depend on how `getProduct` is intended to be used - i.e. whether it designed to be run on the client or server.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading getProduct via '@/sanity/sanity-utils' using a [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

```
export default async function ProductDetails({ params }) {
  const slug = params.product;
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getProduct(slug)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setProduct(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }, [] /* [] means it will load only once when component is mounted */)

  console.log("product",product)


  return (JSX)
}
```